# Alternate visibility for 2 tables

Tags: c#, html

I am having this kind of structure in a Web Application where depending on the user's choices Table_1 or Table_2 is given visibility; they never can be both visible.

```
<table>
    <tr><td>
           <table id="Table_1" runat="server" visible="false">
               <tr><td>...</td></tr>
               <tr><td>
                       <asp:GridView>
                       <asp:Linkbutton>
                       <asp:FormView>
               </td></tr>
           </table>
           <table id="Table_2" runat="server" visible="false">
               <tr><td>...</td></tr>
               <tr><td>
                       <asp:GridView>
               </td></tr>
           </table>
     </td></tr>
</table>
```

The strange thing is that this works only if the hole code block for table 2 is on top. If I switch them back to the way described by the code, table_2 never will show up. I do not add anything more. Just by switching the two tables in the code, once the result is correct, while in the other case it isn't.

What can this be related to?

### Martin

Code that controls visibility:

```
    protected void GridView01_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FilterDDLResponsable.SelectedIndex = -1;
    GridView3.Visible = true;
    GridView3.EditIndex = -1;
    Table_1.Visible = true;
    Table_2.Visible = false;
    GridView3.DataBind();
    ButtonEditMode.Visible = false;
    ButtonSendHWReminderSeries.Visible = false;
    if (AdminUser.Text == "1")
    {
        AddButton.Visible = true;
    }
    LabelAuditID.Text = Convert.ToString(GridView01.SelectedValue);
    if(ActivateTabletView.Checked == true)
    {
        GridView01.Columns[12].Visible = true;
        GridView01.Columns[13].Visible = true;
        GridView01.Columns[14].Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        GridView01.Columns[12].Visible = false;
        GridView01.Columns[13].Visible = false;
        GridView01.Columns[14].Visible = false;
    }
    FillGrid();
}
```

and the Grid's row LinkButton onClick method:

```
    protected void OpenAudit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)(sender);
    string AuditID = btn.CommandArgument;
    Table_1.Visible = false;
    Table_2.Visible = true;
    LabelAuditID.Text = AuditID;
    foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in GridView01.Rows)
    {
        if ((int)GridView01.DataKeys[gvRow.DataItemIndex].Value == Convert.ToUInt32(AuditID))
        {
            GridView01.SelectedIndex = gvRow.DataItemIndex;
            break;
        }
    }
    FillQuestionsGrid();
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code you have written to control the visibility of the tables?

Comment: Your HTML as written contains four unclosed elements.

Comment: @Harsh: I added the code that controls the visibility

Comment: @Amy: if you are referring to the GridView, FormView and LinkButton tags, than it's ok. I used them just to describe what was going on in that table.

Comment: I wrapped the tables into Div's and assigned visibility to them, using exactly the same logic as with the tables, and it works both ways as one would expect. Somehow the table works in a different way. Strange???!